# SCASD wont find strings

Tags: assembly, x86

I am having some trouble understanding how SCASD works. I understand it is supposed to find strings however I don't understand why when I try using it I can't seem to get it to find strings even when I point EDI directly at the address of the string.

How do I get SCASD to find a string?

code at the moment:

```
B8 44435245         | mov eax,41414141                      
BF A8FC9704         | mov edi,<An address that points to 41414141>                      
AF                  | scasd                                 
75 F2               | jne 497FEA2
```

The jump always activates and I don't know why.

Comment: You know `41414141` decimal isn't the same thing as `0x41414141` hex, right?  You can see from your machine code that the `mov`'s immediate isn't `0x41414141`.  I'm guessing that your "address that points to 41414141" is pointing to a `0x41414141` dword.

Comment: Yeah, x64dbg strips the 0x off it so when I copied them out and edited it to make it a bit easier to read the 0x's got lost. In EAX there is a DWORD containing 0x41414141 and EDI holds an address that points at a DWORD 0x41414141

Comment: No, that was my point.  In EAX there's a DWORD `0x44435245` (or actually the byte-reversal of that because if this is an `ndisasm` listing those are the bytes in memory order but x86 is little-endian).  Look at the immediate for the `mov` to EAX in the machine code, or just use a debugger.  It's not `41414141` decimal, though; that would be `0x277edfd`.